# openshift python app serve images

Tags: python, image

i am developing a simple python based site using wsgi.py as the only script right now. I am looking to serve a logo - a png file. Not clear where to deposit the png file and how to refer to it in the html (i.e. img src). thanks for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I use Django on OpenShift and set the STATIC_ROOT to

```
os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'),'wsgi','static')
```

This puts all of my static files (css,images, ect.) in ~/app-root/repo/wsgi/static/

In the HTML I can refer to this directory using /static/

So to access the css: /static/style.css
Or a logo: /static/logo.png

Comment: thanks. I am not sure how to change the "root" for a plain python wsgi.py script. perhaps i should look at a framework. srini